# Store associated value from one table to another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**Table one**

```
Id       subject       class     teacher
1        English         1          1
2        Math            1          2
3        SST             1          3
4        Computer        1          1
5        Physics         1          3
6        Chemistry       1          3
```

Each subject assigned to particular teacher, some subject has same teacher.

Now i want to store values in another table having these fields and other fields as well.

**Table Two**

```
id       subject        teacher
```

Whereas form only post subject ids, how can i get teacher id against each subject id from Table one and store it in table two?

Comment: i am looking for some idea. thing about using array..

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking for how to use relational databases and foreign keys? If so I would read up on how a relational database works and that will answer your question. If the question is about how to do this in code then please state that and also post your attempt at it.

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: if i have to add 1000 records then it will generate 1000 queries. isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. Are you asking for how to use relational databases and foreign keys? If so I would read up on how a relational database works and that will answer your question. If the question is about how to do this in code then please state that and also post your attempt at it.

What i think you want to do is get the of the subject posted, i.e. query the database :

```
SELECT subject, teacher FROM table_one WHERE id = 'POSTED_ID'
```

Then insert the new record into the table two, something like :

```
INSERT INTO table_two (subject, teacher) VALUES ('subject_value', 'teacher_value')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it is possible for one record. Real issue is what about multiple records?

Comment: Could you provide more detail? I'm not sure what you mean about multiple records. If you want to insert multiple you can do this:

    INSERT INTO table_two (subject, teacher) VALUES ('subject_value', 'teacher_value'), ('subject_value2', 'teacher_value2')

Again, not exactly sure what your goal is so the more detail you can provide the better i'll be able to help